# How to generate specific function using BSpline command?

Tags: functions, interpolation, splines

I want to generate an approximation function that fits a curve to points.  My goal is to obtain an actual formula. Is this possible with `BSplineFunction`?  Using the following code:

```
pts = {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, -1}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}};
f = BSplineFunction[pts]
```

the `PiecewiseExpand` command does not work. Is there another way to obtain the formula?

Comment: The formula depends on the `SplineDegree` you ask for. If you ask for a [`SplineDegree` of `1`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mBqP5.png) it could indeed be divided in `Piecewise` functions, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Öskå Doesn't SplineDegree of 1 just generate lines between the points?

Comment: It does indeed, but so does `ListLinePlot`. I don't think there is a command for what you want, you need to make something out.

Comment: Do you expect the `{{1,0},{5,1}}` line shown in `Plot[f[x], {x,0,1}]` to be here in the `Piecewise` function?

Answer (score 4):

It's difficult to answer this question definitively, without more detail on the type of function that you're after.  As you refer to the `PiecewiseExpand` function, I'm rather guessing that you're looking for a single, piecewise linear function that passes through the points.  If so, perhaps this works:

```
affineFormula[{{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}}, x_] := 
  y1 + (y2 - y1) (x - x1)/(x2 - x1) /; x1 != x2;
piecewiseFormula[pts : {{_, _} ..}, x_] := Piecewise[Table[
   {affineFormula[pair, x], pair[[1, 1]] <= x < pair[[2, 1]]}, 
  {pair,Partition[pts, 2, 1]}]];
```

Thus, for your points we have

```
pts = {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, -1}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}};
pw[x_] = piecewiseFormula[pts, x]
```

[image]

Here's a plot:

```
Plot[pw[x], {x, 1, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But again, there are many types of functions that can pass through the points.  Here's a simple way to obtain a polynomial, for example.

```
p[x_] = InterpolatingPolynomial[pts, x]
Plot[p[x], {x, 1, 5}, Epilog -> Point[pts]]
(* Out: 1 + (2 + (-3 + (2 - 7/8 (-4 + x)) (-3 + x)) (-2 + x)) (-1 + x) *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Would one not expect `f = Interpolation[pts, InterpolationOrder -> 1]; PiecewiseExpand[f]` to work?

Comment: @chris I think it might be reasonable to implement PiecewiseExpand for InterpolatingFunctions but I don't see any reason to expect it. Interpolation is much older (V2) and lives in the numerical domain. PiecewiseExpand (V5) is primarily algebraic and is simply meant to simplify nested Piecewise expressions. How might PiecewiseExpand work with an InterpolatingFunction generated by NDSolve and containing zillions of sub-intervals?

Comment: well it would return A very large output was generated… :-)